# How to remove HTML tags in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

```
$variables['slide_one_description'] =  wordwrap(theme_get_setting('slide_one_description','metroman'), 20,"<br>");
```

In the above, I set the variable for slider description, I just want to apply line break for after some length, but the above code print HTML `br` tag instead of line break.

Note: description is a dynamic content and I want to solution in Drupal 8.

Comment: Do you mean that in your slider you actually see Something like "My text<br>"?

Comment: Are you printing $variables['slide_one_description'] in the twig template?

Comment: yes i want to print in twig template and it properly print when i am using {{ slide_one_description | raw }}

Answer (score 0):

There used to be functions such as SafeMarkup::checkPlain() that performed this function, but they have been largely deprecated and removed. Most of the time, Twig will do your text sanitization for you, but there are times where you just need an HTML-stripped value in PHP in Drupal.

For example, PHP has a [strip_tags()][1] function that does exactly what the name implies.

Or, for a more Drupal-friendly way, just pass the value through a t() function and use a @ replacement to force plain text. Here's an example of how it works:

```
$value = '<p>Here is a <b>value</b> with HTML.<br>Let's remove it.</p>';
$stripped_value = t('@value', ['@value' => $value]);
```

This is a trivial example, of course, but you can apply it to other scenarios. Also, this just gets rid of <br> tags, rather than replacing them with line breaks; you'd need a PHP function like the following to replace <br> tags with something else:

```
function br2nl($string)
{
  return preg_replace('/\<br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', "\n", $string);
}
```

Comment: You could also expose this br2nl function as a twig function. Briefly mentioned on [this page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/functions-in-twig-templates). Or you could just install the [twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module and use it's [Preg Replace Filter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet#s-preg-replace-filter).

Comment: Agreed - there are several Twig-based solutions, which I glossed over with my early "Most of the time, Twig will do your text sanitization for you..." statement. I chose to show a PHP-based solution in case there was a time where the data needed to be in PHP for one reason or another - such as doing a transformation on the derived data in a PHP pre-processor (for any one of a million possible reasons :) ).